# AVX512 transpose 8 ZMM registers of 16-bit elements

Tags: assembly, transpose, avx512

For example, continuous 32 data are loaded into each register,each number is 16 bits.And the numbers below represent coefficient subscripts.

```
zmm1:0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  
zmm2:32 ... ... 63  
zmm3:64 ... ... 95  
zmm4:96 ... ...127  
zmm5:128... ...159  
zmm6:160... ...191  
zmm7:192... ...223  
zmm8:224... ...255
```

change to ↓
The coefficients are stored by transposing.The subscripts with an interval of 8.Such as:

```
zmm9: 0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 88 96 104 112 120 128 136 144 152 160 168 176 184 192 200 208 216 224 232 240 248    
zmm10:1 9 17 ... ... 249  
zmm11:2 10 18 ... ...250  
zmm12:3 11 19 ... ...251  
zmm13:4 12 20 ... ...252  
zmm14:5 13 21 ... ...253  
zmm15:6 14 22 ... ...254  
zmm16:7 15 23 ... ...255
```

Does the AVX512 instruction set have an instruction to meet this requirement?
I looked for the official manual, but couldn't find it. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you'll have to implement a transposition algorithm.  The usual approach is a recursive transposition where you recursively split the matrix into four blocks, then transpose each block and finally swap top right with bottom left.

Comment: Every instruction writes at most one register (except `vzeroupper` / `vzeroall`).  You probably want `vpermt2w` as the first step building block, except that it's multiple uops even on Ice Lake and later.  A merge-masking `vpermb` could maybe work to get the data you need into one register; hopefully single-uop `vpermt2d` could deal with the result of that as inputs to the next wider stage of transposing.